# How to disable close modal box when click background?

Tags: joomla-3.x, modal, popup

I use Joomla modal to popup an internal link.

```
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
<a class="modal" href="contact-us.html" rel="{size: {x: 480, y: 500}, handler:'iframe'}">Contact Us</a>
```

I don't want to close the popup window when I click the background. Does anyone know how to prevent the modal closure on that user event?

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that `behavior.modal` uses Mootools and has been removed in Joomla 4, so I'd suggest using `bootstrap.renderModal` instead, which will ensure J4 compatibility.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactModal">Contact Us</button>
```

**PHP:**

```
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

echo HTMLHelper::_(
    'bootstrap.renderModal',
    'contactModal',
    [
        'url'        => 'contact-us.html',
        'title'      => 'Contact Us',
        'backdrop'   => 'static',
        'modalWidth' => 40,
        'bodyHeight' => 60,
        'footer'     => '<a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>'
    ]
);
```

Note that `'backdrop' => 'static',` will prevent the modal closing when clicking the background.

Comment: I'm using Joomla 3.9.x, how to do it in Joomla 3.9?

Comment: The above is for Joomla 3.9